# Value Fetching From Sql Is Not Printing

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image]

I am using `PHP` as backend
In this I am getting order details by use of `MySQL`
All the value printing but `address` is not printing
If the `address` field less words, its printing, otherwise it is blank

Please help me out

[image]

Comment: Make an effort and paste your code as __text__

Comment: you can check with error_reporting(E_ALL); at the beginning. if you dont get any error then first print query(in your case $sql variable) and check if it is correct or not if you don't have much knowledge about sql query than you can copy and try to run in phpMyAdmin. you will get en error if have any in your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following steps:

first of all, see if you get some errors from mysqli which are not printed. I recommend to put this after

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

If there is no error, be sure, that the GET-paramter userid has a value and is not null. After that you cant print your variable $result with print_r($result) to see, if $result has a value.

If that all dont help, I would print_r($r), because you can see, if your query gets any data from your server.

Is that all right and you dont get any content, you should try to you another way to connect to your database. I prefer PDO. This tutorial shows the most important features from PDO https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Good luck and I hope, this helps you.